# comparing different columns and rows on the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

We are making a simple database for our school programme. we have a table like this:

```
ID     A        B

1    John    Stacey
2    Stacey  Mark
3    Candice Rick
4    Stacey  Rick
5    Rick    Stacey
```

If we input Stacey's name, we display the number of rows where:

for every row (say, x and y)

```
rowX-ColumnA = rowY-ColumnB AND rowY-ColumnA = rowX-ColumnB
```

in this case, it should output:

2 rows:

```
4    Stacey  Rick
5    Rick    Stacey
```

Thanks! We have more than 100 students so we won't be able to do this manually. Again, I appreciate any hint.

Comment: You can either use an equal or a `LIKE` SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE A LIKE 'Stacey%' OR B LIKE 'Stacey%'

Comment: Your second condition is not correct for your example.
Are you looking for something like `RowX = John Stacy and RowY = Stacy  John` ?

Comment: did you try any query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query my friend:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 
inner join table1 t2 on t1.A = t2.B and t1.B = t2.A;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a58d/1)

Comment: oh my god. it worked. Thank you very much. Im an elementary history teacher and dont know much about programming. Anyway, thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
SELECT p1.* 
FROM People p1
     INNER JOIN
     People p2 ON p1.A=p2.B AND p1.B=p2.A
WHERE p1.A='Stacey' OR p1.B='Stacey'
```

See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/acbcdf/4) SQLfiddle (SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example. I think you're probably looking for something like this:

`select stu1.* from students stu1, 
                    students stu2
              where stu1.last_name = stu2.first_name
union
select stu1.* from students stu1, 
                    students stu2
              where stu1.first_name = stu2.last_name;`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9bbf/2/0
Above answer was based on your example of John Stacy , Stacy Rick.